# How to read line by line and parse from a file in python?

Tags: python, parsing, readline

How to read line by line and parse from a file in python?

I am new to python.

The first line of input is the number of simulations. 
The next line is the number of rows(x), followed by a single space, and followed by number of columns (y).
The next group of y lines will have x number of characters, with a single period ('.') representing a blank space and a single capitol “A” representing a starting Agent.

My code got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    numSims = int (line)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Thanks for your help.

Input.txt

```
2   --- 2 simulations
3 3  -- 3*3 map
.A.  --map
AA.
A.A
2 2  --2*2 map
AA  --map
.A
```

```
def main(cls, args):
    numSims = 0
    path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/input.txt') 
    f = open(path) 
    line = f.readlines() 
    numSims = int (line)
    print numSims
    k=0
    while k < numSims:
        minPerCycle = 1
        row = 0
        col = 0
        xyLine= f.readLines()
        row = int(xyLine.split()[0]) 
        col = int(xyLine.split()[1])
        myMap = [[Spot() for j in range(col)] for i in range(row)] 
        ## for-while
        i = 0
        while i < row:
            myLine = cls.br.readLines()
            ## for-while
            j = 0
            while j < col:
                if (myLine.charAt(j) == 'B'):
                    cls.myMap[i][j] = Spot(True)
                else:
                    cls.myMap[i][j] = Spot(False)
                j += 1
            i += 1
```

For Spot.py

Spot.py

```
class Spot(object):
isBunny = bool()
nextCycle = 0
UP = 0
RIGHT = 1
DOWN = 2
LEFT = 3
SLEEP = 4

def __init__(self, newIsBunny):
    self.isBunny = newIsBunny
    self.nextCycle = self.UP
```

Comment: So, what is wrong with the code given?

Comment: You should try the atpy module - it easily reads in and parses columns and all you have to do is specify the file type (ascii, in this case) and the delimiter.

Comment: @Mike: regarding your Spot class... I think you still have got it all wrong about how Python classes work. Please don't try to fake type declarations for variables, they're neither needed nor can they prevent e.g. this: `s = Spot(7); s.isBunny = 'joe'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your errors are numerous, here are the ones I've found so far:

1. The line `numSims = (int)line` does not do what you think it does. Python does not have C casts, you need to *call* the `int` type instead:

   ```
   numSims = int(line)
   ```

   You compound this error later on by using an uppercase spelling of `Int`:

   ```
   row = (Int)(xyLine.split(" ")[0])
   col = (Int)(xyLine.split(" ")[1])
   ```

   Correct these in a similar manner:

   ```
   row = int(xyLine.split()[0])
   col = int(xyLine.split()[1])
   ```

   and since the default for `.split()` is to split on whitespace you can leave out the `" "` argument. Better yet, combine them into one line:

   ```
   row, col = map(int, xyLine.split())
   ```
2. You never increment `k`, so your `while k < numSims:` loop will continue forever, so you'll get an EOF error. Use a `for` loop instead:

   ```
   for k in xrange(numSims):
   ```

   You don't need to use `while` anywhere in this function, they can all be replaced with `for variable in xrange(upperlimit):` loops.
3. Python strings have no `.charAt` method. Use `[index]` instead:

   ```
   if myLine[j] == 'A':
   ```

   but since `myLine[j] == 'A'` is a boolean test, you can simplify your `Spot()` instantiation like so:

   ```
   for i in xrange(row):
       myLine = f.readLine()
       for j in xrange(col):
           cls.myMap[i][j] = Spot(myLine[j] == 'A')
   ```
4. There is no need to initialize variables quite so much in Python. You can get of most of the `numSims = 0` and `col = 0` lines, etc. if you are assigning a new value on a following line.
5. You create a 'myMap`variable but then ignore it by referring to`cls.myMap` instead.
6. There is no handling of multible maps here; the last map in the file would overwrite any preceding map.

Rewritten version:

```
def main(cls, args):
    with open(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/input.txt')) as f:
        numSims = int(f.readline())
        mapgrid = []
        for k in xrange(numSims):
            row, col = map(int, f.readline().split())  
            for i in xrange(row):
                myLine = f.readLine()
                mapgrid.append([])
                for j in xrange(col):
                    mapgrid[i].append(Spot(myLine[j] == 'A'))
         # store this map somewhere?
         cls.myMaps.append(mapgrid)
```

Comment: Wow, that's an amazingly thorough analysis of some questionable code . . . nice job!

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake by naming a variable `map`. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

While [Martijn Pieters does a very good job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12611732/395321) in explaining how your code could be made better, I suggest an entirely different approach, i.e. using a [Monadic Parser Combinator](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Monadic%20Parser%20Combinators%22) library like e.g. [Parcon](http://www.opengroove.org/parcon/parcon-tutorial.html). That allows you to go beyond context free grammars and to easily modify your parser during runtime based on information extracted by the current parsing process:

```
from functools import partial
from parcon import (Bind, Repeat, CharIn, number, End,
                    Whitespace, ZeroOrMore, CharNotIn)

def array(parser, size):
    return Repeat(parser, min=size, max=size)

def matrix(parser, sizes):
    size, sizes = sizes[0], sizes[1:]
    return array(matrix(parser, sizes) if sizes else parser, size)

comment = '-' + ZeroOrMore(CharNotIn('\n')) + '\n'

sims = Bind(number[int],
            partial(array,
                    Bind(number[int] + number[int],
                         partial(matrix,
                                 CharIn('.A')['A'.__eq__])))) + End()

text = '''
2   --- 2 simulations
3 3  -- 3*3 map
.A.  --map
AA.
A.A
2 2  --2*2 map
AA  --map
.A
'''

import pprint
pprint.pprint(sims.parse_string(text, whitespace=Whitespace() | comment))
```

Result:

```
$ python numsims.py
[[False, True, False], [True, True, False], [True, False, True]]
[[True, True], [False, True]]
```

At first it's a bit of a mind twister, like all things monadic. But the flexibility and succinctness of expression are well worth the time invested in learning about monads.